# Match document if it contains multiple nested documents in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document that contains arrays of nested documents. I have a requirement to return matches if the document contains all of the specified nested documents.

here is the relevant part of the mapping:

```
"element": {
  "dynamic": "false",
  "properties": {
    "tenantId": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    },
    "fqn": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    },
    "id": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    },
    "type": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    },
    "tags": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "dataSourceId": {
          "type": "long",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "value": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The goal is to be able to return elements that contain all of a list of tags (although the element is permitted to contain additional tags beyond the search requirement).

Here is what I have so far:

```
{
   "query": {
     "bool": {
       "filter": {
          "nested": {
             "path": "tags",
             "query": {
                "bool": {
                   "must": [
                      {
                        "bool": {
                          "must":{
                             "term": { "tags.name": "name1" },
                             "term": { "tags.value": "value1" }
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "bool": {
                          "must":{
                             "term": { "tags.name": "name2" },
                             "term": { "tags.value": "value2" }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                   ]
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that it returns 0 hits with multiple tag values (it works fine for a single value). I believe that this is because the query is requiring that a tag have multiple names and values in order to match, which obviously can't happen. Does anyone know how to query for elements that contain all of a list of tags?

edit: this is using elasticsearch 5.0

Comment: Are you trying todo this ? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/_finding_multiple_exact_values.html

Comment: @JamesKn I looked into terms queries, but it is my understanding that they're an implicit "or" operation on the values. I need an "and" operation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We figured it out. The answer was to create two nested queries, instead of having two clauses to the same nested query.

```
{
 "query":{
   "bool":{
     "must":[{
        "nested":{
           "path":"tags",
           "query":{
              "bool":{
                 "must":[
                    {"term":{"tags.name":"name1"}},
                    {"term":{"tags.value":"value1"}}
                 ]
              }
           }
        }
     },
     {
        "nested":{
           "path":"tags",
           "query":{
              "bool":{
                 "must":[
                    {"term":{"tags.name":"name2"}},
                    {"term":{"tags.value":"value2"}}
                 ]
              }
           }
        }
     }]
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Came up against this issue and your answer saved me a lot of headache, thanks!

Comment: is there a better way to do this? if you have to apply 5-6 conditions on nested attributes, the query will become huge!